# IF statement in MS SQL when function return empty string

Tags: sql-server

I need to check when function in MS SQL return empty string ('') in insert to table and handle condition. I don't know how. I use this syntax:

```
INSERT
INTO [DB].[dbo].[TablesNames]
(Name)
VALUES
(CASE 
      WHEN [dbo].Function(@ID, @ExternalName, @Level) IS '' 
      THEN @Name 
      ELSE [dbo].Function(@ID, @ExternalName, @Level))
```

How is correct syntax in this case? Thx for advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would be more inclined to write this as:

```
INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[TablesNames](Name)
    SELECT (CASE WHEN x = '' THEN @Name ELSE x END)
    FROM (SELECT [dbo].Function(@ID, @ExternalName, @Level) as val) x;
```

Functions usually incur an overhead when they are called.  This formulation gives SQL Server an opportunity to only evaluate the function once.

A couple more things:

- I don't recognize `IS`.  Might you mean `IS NULL`?
- If you are looking at blank values (empty strings) do you also want to consider `NULL` values?